# How to force SQLite to have not only lower case fields?

Tags: php, postgresql, sqlite

We have a huge PHP (HHVM) application.
The production database is `postgresql`, and have many fields like: `userId, accountId.` In pgsql the fields are case sensitive, and we have to quote them: `"accountId", "userId".`

For testing we would like to use sqlite memory database, but the field names are all lowercase in the result of the select.
These fields from the sqlite database are like userid and accountid.
So the properties of the objects are not the same, making lots of difficulties.
For example an entry will not have `$entry->userId` but `$entry->userid.`

Is there a way to have not only lowercase field names?

Comment: In short you probably can't avoid this issue but you can probably code your tests to use a transformation of columns instead of their actual names. However without any code we can't know what's in the realm of feasibility

Comment: The main problem here is that we get back explicit objects directly instead of stdclass from the PDO. Maybe magic get can help. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a trait with magic gets and sets can solve the issue.
https://pastebin.com/cEFKWU1v
However a more elegant solution would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems to work as expected:

```
drop table if exists "MyTable";
create table "MyTable"("MyId" int, "MyStr" text);
insert into "MyTable" values (1, 'str');

select * from "MyTable";

MyId        MyStr     
----------  ----------
1           str

select sqlite_version();

sqlite_version()
----------------
3.9.1
```

See also [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0032e/1)

Anyway, I'd suggest to install Postgres locally. It's straightforward with their [GUI installers.](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

Comment: Just a quick try:
object(stdClass)#2743 (1) {
    ["tokens"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
  }

Comment: You have a quick try in the answer. SQLite do allow case-sensitive identifiers. You have a problem with your tools not with SQLite.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer, it really supports it, the PDO has an attribute:
$connection->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_CASE, \PDO::CASE_NATURAL);

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best option is to modify your SQL statements to use quoted column aliases:

```
SELECT
  accountid AS "accountId",
  userid AS "userId",
  ...
FROM
  ...
```

This is supported by (almost?) all SQL engines and makes your statements portable.

Answer (score -2):

no there isnt but u can bind your columns with your code models. there is many database library that can do this

Comment: Can I ask a short example? I don't know exactly what you think of.

Comment: i didnt know php but in android we use models, we use a library that when we define our tables in models it  can translate our models to table models . i think there is a library for php too

Comment: Thanks. We use PDO and it gives back explicit objects for simplicity.
So when we query the db, we get back in this case Entry models directly.
The downvote was not me :)

Comment: OK : ) my reputation is low and i need it for vote privilege :)  thanks